# Rotate a Matrix (2D Array) by X.XX°

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I wasn't able to find anything on the following topic, since most questions asked to rotate the array around 90°, 180°, 270°, which would be to easy actually.

I need to turn a matrix for all possible kinds of degrees, like as if I rotate an image in photoshop (programmatically, I don't need a GUI or something similar for this). This will lead to small errors in the result, which won't bother much.

Picture rotating should be a quite similar approach, so I think there should be tons of solutions to this problem. Is there an easy way in java to do this or do I have to calculate the position for every entry by myself?

Note: The array I'm using is a "binary" array, filled with Integers that are of the value "0" and "1".

PS: This will change the size of the "bounding box" around the matrix. This is no problem at this point.

---

Edit: I try to give an example how this could look like:

**Initial:**

```
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
```

Rotate 20.12° at the rotation point [3][2].

**Result:**

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 1 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 1, 0, 0 }
```

This looks extremely useless, but the more the size of this matrix is, the more accurate those results will be. I work with matrices much bigger than this example. :)

Comment: only 0 and 1s? integers? your rotation will be very "pixelated"

Comment: There are readily available solutions to the problem of rotating a picture, such as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html. But to apply them to a matrix of 0 and 1 would require some processing on the way in and on the way out. So you may not find those solutions useful to you.

Comment: Is it OK if the rotated matrix has fewer "1" entries than the original matrix?

Comment: Maybe it would help to understand your intention. What is the usecase of such a rotated matrix?

Comment: @chris: I have jigsaw-puzzle pieces (initially a binary image) that I need to rotate in a straight position (to be able to do a matching-check later). Here is an example of such a piece: http://pastebin.com/aN35GRgL (zoom out for a better view or copy the content to Notepad++ and zoom out there). Thanks guys. :)

Comment: @DavidK: If it's "more or less" the same, yeah.

Comment: @DavidK Rotation with nearest neighbor interpolation should satisfy the constraint of having only 0 and 1.

Comment: @beaker My thinking was that in some cases the nearest neighbor of one point's image might also be the nearest neighbor of another point's image. You can only put one "1" in each cell of the array, so you'd lose one. Based on the application, however, it does appear that this could be acceptable. Another option is you find the exact preimage of the destination matrix and apply nearest-neighbor to that, in which case I think you might end up with a few extra 1s.

Comment: Yes, you might end up with extra 1s (or extra 0s), but all of the values would be 0 or 1. You wouldn't have to worry about other values creeping in.

Comment: I edited my question, hope this clarifies some points. :)

Comment: I'm curious whether the current answer is appropriate for your (or if not: why not?). One could also implement this without converting to an image, and one has to carefully consider whether such a conversion-based approach is appropraite or not, but since you seem to operate on *images* anyhow (although they are represented by a "matrix"), it might be fine.

Comment: @Marco13: I'm actually on it. I don't like the idea of turning it back into a BufferedImage just to use the rotation method there. Though, the idea is smart. I do this now with a rotation matrix (simplest solution, went through different things and you always land back there). I can post my answer when I finished it. :) What you need for this is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 1):

I would write two methods: one to convert your array to a BufferedImage and one the other way around. Both things should be easy to implement. The BufferedImage can be rotated with AffineTransform etc.
Not very elegant but to do with standard java code without third party stuff.
And you got images to show the result graphically.
This implementation does the things mentioned above:

```
package rasterImage;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class MatrixRotator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MatrixRotator() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButtonDoIt = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanelOrg = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanelRot = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButtonDoIt.setText("Do it");
        jButtonDoIt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonDoItActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanelOrg.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelOrgLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelOrg);
        jPanelOrg.setLayout(jPanelOrgLayout);
        jPanelOrgLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelOrgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanelOrgLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelOrgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanelRot.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelRotLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelRot);
        jPanelRot.setLayout(jPanelRotLayout);
        jPanelRotLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelRotLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanelRotLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelRotLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButtonDoIt)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanelOrg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanelRot, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jPanelRot, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButtonDoIt)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanelOrg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void printRaster(int[][] raster) {
        int rows = raster.length;
        int cols = raster[0].length;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                int content = raster[r][c];
                System.out.print(content);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage convert2image(int[][] raster) {
        int rows = raster.length;
        int cols = raster[0].length;

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                int content = raster[r][c];
                if (content == 1) {
                    g.fillRect(c, r, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

    private int[][] convert2raster(BufferedImage img) {
        int cols = img.getWidth();
        int rows = img.getHeight();
        int[][] raster = new int[rows][cols];

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                int content = img.getRGB(c, r);
                if (content == -1) {
                    raster[r][c] = 1;
                } else {
                    raster[r][c] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return raster;
    }

    private void jButtonDoItActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        int[][] raster = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};
        printRaster(raster);

        //convert raster to image:
        BufferedImage img = convert2image(raster);

        //create rotated image ('large enough'):
        BufferedImage imgRot = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

        //rotate the image:
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(20.12));
        imgRot.createGraphics().drawImage(img, tx, null);

        //convert image to raster:
        raster = convert2raster(imgRot);
        printRaster(raster);

        //draw it:
        jPanelOrg.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        jPanelRot.getGraphics().drawImage(imgRot, 0, 0, null);
    }                                           

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MatrixRotator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonDoIt;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelOrg;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelRot;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: +1 for great effort and not using 3rd party libraries. But I don't need an image for a graphical output nor do I like the idea to turn the matrix back to an Image just to use a rotating function. This are a lot lines of code, I'm currently doing it with less "overhead" and will post my solution when I finished it. :) Basically what you need for a matrix rotation is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Yes it's quite a lot of code but i wanted a running example (the most of the lines are swing-related i think). The core idea of it is to convert it back and force from/to a raster image and use the `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform`. So what - maybe someone else find it useful :)

Comment: You use the BufferedImage approach, this is what I dislike a bit (overhead). But maybe I'll have to come back to this, my code seems to have a bug somewhere and I'm searching since days what could be the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out and discussed in the comments, there are some degrees of freedom when implementing this.

Particularly, in some cases, it's simply not clear what should happen. First of all, the "bounds" of the array will change when it is rotated. Then, you'll encounter aliasing artifacts, when one entry of the input array lies exactly between two cells of the output array after the rotation.

However, disregarding these minor questions, there are basically only two solutions for this:

- **"Forward-mapping"**:

  For each cell of the *input* array, one can compute the rotated position of the cell, and write the value from the input cell into this rotated position of the output array.
- **"Backward-mapping"**:

  For each cell of the *output* array, one can compute the position that this cell had in the input array, and fetch the value from there.

In both cases, the rotation could simply be done using an `AffineTransform` that rotates about a certain point.

From a practical point of view, this does not make much difference - as long as the resolution (that is, the size in this case) of both arrays is the same! There will, however, be differences regarding the aliasing artifacts: While the "forward" method may occasionally "swallow" points (and place a 0 where you'd expect a 1), the backward method may occasionally place a 1 where you'd expect a 0.

The implementation of both methods might then simply look like this:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;

public class MatrixRotate
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a[][] = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        };

        System.out.println("Initial:");
        System.out.println(toString(a));

        for (int angleDeg=10; angleDeg<=180; angleDeg+=10)
        {
            int[][] r0 = rotateForward(a, 2.0, 2.0, Math.toRadians(angleDeg));
            System.out.println("Rotated about "+angleDeg+
                " degrees using forward method:");
            System.out.println(toString(r0));

            int[][] r1 = rotateBackward(a, 2.0, 2.0, Math.toRadians(angleDeg));
            System.out.println("Rotated about "+angleDeg+
                " degrees using backward method:");
            System.out.println(toString(r1));

        }
    }


    private static int[][] rotateForward(int a[][], 
        double cx, double cy, double angleRad)
    {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToRotation(angleRad, cx, cy);
        int rotated[][] = create(a);
        for (int r=0; r<a.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<a[r].length; c++)
            {
                Point p0 = new Point(c,r);
                Point p1 = new Point();
                at.transform(p0, p1);
                if (isValid(p1, rotated))
                {
                    rotated[p1.y][p1.x] = a[p0.y][p0.x];
                }
            }
        }
        return rotated;
    }

    private static int[][] rotateBackward(int a[][], 
        double cx, double cy, double angleRad)
    {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToRotation(angleRad, cx, cy);
        try
        {
            at.invert();
        }
        catch (NoninvertibleTransformException e)
        {
            // Can not happen here
        }
        int rotated[][] = create(a);
        for (int r=0; r<a.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<a[r].length; c++)
            {
                Point p0 = new Point(c,r);
                Point p1 = new Point();
                at.transform(p0, p1);
                if (isValid(p1, a))
                {
                    rotated[p0.y][p0.x] = a[p1.y][p1.x];
                }
            }
        }
        return rotated;
    }

    private static boolean isValid(Point p, int a[][])
    {
        return 
            p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0 &&
            p.y < a.length && p.x < a[p.y].length;
    }

    private static int[][] create(int a[][])
    {
        int b[][] = new int[a.length][];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            b[i] = new int[a[i].length];
        }
        return b;
    }

    private static String toString(int a[][])
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String format = "%2d";
        for (int r=0; r<a.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<a[r].length; c++)
            {
                sb.append(String.format(format, a[r][c]));
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: A very mature looking approach. Thx. I'm currently to far in the process to throw my progress all over, but I might consider this solution as a "rework" of my algorithm. I'm currently in a "prototyping mode". :) Thank you very much Marco13!